# Is there a way to do this? Discord commando btw

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to add a command on my `discord.js` bot on which you type:

`-si <imagename>`

To set the server icon to this image.
This is the code I have. But the program doesn’t load, it loads for a split second and dies right after with absolutely no error. Please help.

```js
const commando=require('discord.js-commando');
console.log("\n ~ Server Icon Changer Online ");
var i=0;
const usr=require('./cred.json');
class cd extends commando.Command{
    constructor(client){
        super(client,{
            name: 'si',
            group: 'channels',
            memberName: 'si',
            description: 'Changes server icon'
        });
    }
    async run(message,args){
        message.delete();
        if(usr.allowedIDs.includes(message.author.id)) {
            guild.setIcon('./ahtm-icon1.png')
             .then(console.log)
             .catch(console.error);
setIcon(icon, reason) {
    return this.client.resolver.resolveImage(icon).then(data => this.edit({ icon: data, reason }));
 }
```

If you do need to contact me:
LilCxmstxin_#0420

My nitro expires the 23rd of December so if you happen to dm me after that

LilCxmstxin_#4108

Answer (score 1):

Is this a peace of your code, or your entire file?

Anyways, at the end are you using `client.login("YOUR TOKEN")`?

Also you are just logging to the console `("\n ~ Server Icon Changer Online ");`, you should do this inside a ready event, in which the bot is online.

A simple example of this event:

`client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready!");
});`